# Ubuntu isn't able to boot: Keyboard backlight function in Sony vaio

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, vaio, sony, backlight

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.5 alongside with Windows 7 and it's been working fine until yesterday. After choosing Ubuntu from the dual boot menu a message appears and says:
"Sony Vaio: couldn't set up keyboard backlight function -16" and after that another screen says: "couldn't write bytes: broken pipe"
I could not solve the problem so I uninstall it and install again twice but the message keeps showing again keyboard backlight......

I should let you know that I have been using it for almost a week in building Android source code and it was good.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Regards,
Saeed.